# Relativistic corrections to first-principles Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, condensed-matter, dirac-equation, many-body

In quantum treatments of solids  it is common to start off discussions by writing down the "full" first-principles Hamiltonian for a group of electrons and nuclei as

$$H = \sum_i \frac{\hat{p}_i^2}{2m_i}+\frac{e^2}{2}\sum_{i,j} \frac{Z_i Z_j}{\vert \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j \vert}$$

This Hamiltonian can in principle be solved for a many body wavefunction $\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\dots, \mathbf{r}_N)$ and contains all the physics of a solid.

There are relativistic corrections that can be made to this Hamiltonian. The simplest is replacing the kinetic energy term with higher order terms in $p$. But there are also spin-dependent terms (like the Zeeman term), and spin orbit coupling as discussed in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476598/can-the-pauli-equation-be-used-to-derive-the-usual-mathbf-l-cdot-mathbf-s-sp).

Let's assume we still want to stay in the comfort of non-relativistic quantum mechanics (particle number is conserved, fixed Coulomb gauge, etc.), but want a more accurate first principles Hamiltonian.

My question is: **what is the correct expression for the many-body Hamiltonian of a group of electrons/nuclei that includes all important relavistic corrections to leading order?**

If you let me rephrase that question in a more hand-wavy way, how do we explicitly include relavistic corrections (Zeeman spin term,  spin-orbit, Darwin, etc.) into the full many body Hamiltonian above to make sure it doesn't leave out important SR physics?

The reason I ask this question is that it is common in solids state texts to include relavistic corrections at the single particle level, but rarely at the level of the "full" many body treatment.

Comment: Looks like this old question never got a good answer! The answer is the Breit Hamiltonian. It has about 7 additional terms, which comprise all of the order $(v/c)^2$ corrections.

Answer (score 1):

As @knzhou hinted, the answer is the complete Breit Hamiltonian. It is described already [here[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit_equation)][1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit_equation), but for completeness, I am posting it here.

Starting with the usual non-relativistic Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_{0} = \sum_{i}\frac{\hat{p}_{i}^{2}}{2m_{i}} + V$, there are six more terms to lowest orders in $v/c$.

- $\hat{H}_{1} = -\frac{1}{8c^{2}}\sum_{i}\frac{\hat{p}_{i}^{4}}{m_{i}^{3}}$ - relativistic correction to kinetic energy.
- $\hat{H}_{2} = - \sum_{i>j} \frac{q_iq_j}{2r_{ij}m_im_jc^2} \left[ \mathbf{\hat{p}}_i\cdot\mathbf{\hat{p}}_j + \frac{(\mathbf{r_{ij}}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{p}}_i)(\mathbf{r_{ij}}\cdot\mathbf{\hat{p}}_j)}{r_{ij}^2} \right]$  - the magnetic interactions between *orbital* angular momentum.
- $\hat{H}_3 = \frac{\mu_{\rm B}}{c} \sum_i \frac{1}{m_i} \mathbf{s}_i\cdot\left[ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}_i)\times\mathbf{\hat{p}}_i + \sum_{j > i} \frac{2q_i}{r_{ij}^3}\mathbf{r}_{ij}\times\mathbf{\hat{p}}_j \right]$ - spin orbit interaction, where $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}_i)$ is the electric field.
- $\hat{H}_4 = \frac{ih}{8 \pi c^2} \sum_{i} \frac{q_i}{m_i^2} \mathbf{\hat{p}}_i\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}_i) $ - the Darwin term
- $\hat{H}_5 = 4\mu_{\rm B}^2 \sum_{i>j} \left\lbrace -\frac{8\pi}{3} (\mathbf{s}_i\cdot\mathbf{s}_j)\delta(\mathbf{r}_{ij}) + \frac{1}{r_{ij}^3}\left[ \mathbf{s}_i\cdot\mathbf{s}_j - \frac{3(\mathbf{s}_i\cdot\mathbf{r}_{ij})(\mathbf{s}_j\cdot\mathbf{r}_{ij})}{r_{ij}^2} \right] \right\rbrace $ - spin-spin magnetic interaction. The first is the contact interaction responsible for Hyperfine splitting, while the second is of the magnetic dipole-dipole type.
- $\hat{H}_6 = 2\mu_{\rm B} \sum_{i} \left[ \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{r}_i)\cdot\mathbf{s}_i + \frac{q_i}{m_ic}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}_i)\cdot\mathbf{\hat{p}}_i \right]$ - Magnetic interaction between spin and orbital angular momentum with an external field.

Comment: Beware though: this Breit-Pauli Hamiltonian is not bounded from below due to the $\sim-p^4$ term. As a consequence, this $H$ is only suitable for first-order perturbation theory, so I'm not sure if it really qualifies as a first-principles Hamiltonian. (You can't solve it variationally; first-order PT is of course fine in practice as long as the problem is massively dominated by non-relativistic effects.) If you want a true relativistic Hamiltonian admitting exact solutions, then you must turn to the original Breit $H$ projected onto the positive energy ("electrons only") subspace.

Comment: Interesting point, but would it not be sufficient to just include one higher power of $+p^6$ to remedy that?

Comment: The problem is that the expansion of the relativistic kinetic energy in powers of $p^2/(mc)^2$ is somewhat questionable. Intuitively speaking, you can always find regions very close to the nuclei where $p^2/(mc)^2>1$ and the square root series breaks down. It turns out that this is not a problem in first order, but you shouldn't rely on the higher powers in a non-perturbative calculation. I mean, if you include the $+p^6$ term, someone could immediately ask on what ground you neglect $-p^8$ (which breaks boundedness again).

Comment: You might find Chapters 16. and 17. of Dyall & Faegri, *Relativistic Quantum Chemistry* interesting.

Comment: @dennismoore94 thanks for the reference! If you also have an answer with your point in mind, I would love to read it!

Answer (score 0):

For a truly relativistic treatment you should start with the Dirac equation and add the periodic lattice potential - it is just as simple, as adding a potential to the Schrödinger equation, as the first equation suggests. It is a good exercise, but it is never done in practice, because band structure calculations are a science in themselves - relativistic treatment is really a minor complication in comparison. Therefore the spin-orbit terms (Rashba, Dresselhaus-D'yakonov-Perel, Elliot-Yafet, etc.) are usually posited on the symmetry (lattice and relativistic) grounds and their constants are determined empirically.

Comment: Of course you can just write out the Dirac equation, but that is not my question. That approach has the added hassle of negative energy (antiparticle) states that are irrelevant, so one would always take a non-relativistic approximation anyways. My question is also not about band structure, but the structure of the "first principles" Hamiltonian.

Comment: I should also point out that this Hamiltonian doesn't make any assumptions about the existence of a crystal lattice, it is just a many-body collection of electrons and nuclei with all particles treated equally.

Comment: Indeed, but this is how one derives relativistic corrections - by starting from the fully relativistic model rather than from the fully non-relativistic one. For a hydrogen atom these are usually worked through in any book treating Dirac equation.

Comment: I agree,  so let me say it differently, my question is asking for the "worked out" non relativistic expression analogous to the hydrogen atom but for a many body system.

Comment: This is a first year QM exercise :)

Comment: Then it should be very easy for you to add to your answer

Comment: Take the hydrogen atom  solution from QM book and add the indices to make it "many body".